# Can't get parameter value from ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, properties

This is part of my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="contextOverride" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>WEB-INF/conf/configuration.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Value("${mavenBuildTimestamp}")
private String mavenBuildTimestamp;
/*...*/
}
```

PropertyPlaceholder seems to be configured properly, because parameters values in `applicationContext.xml` are substituted correctly.
But value of `mavenBuildTimestamp` is `${mavenBuildTimestamp}` instead of property real value.

What should I do to retrieve property value from PropertyPlaceholder in java code?

Comment: Is your controller class on the scan path?

Comment: @Reimeus Controller is working properly and other `@Autowired` fields have correct values.

Comment: is mavenBuildTimestamp a value in your configuration.properties file? From its name it sounds like being generated dynamically at compile time. Also can you inject any other value using @Value("${yourProp}") on the same controller? Try for testing purposes